# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot have circular references in bean class

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While executing the following Spark command:

```
Dataset<Row> xDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(xs, X.class);
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class java.lang.ClassLoader
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.getSchema(SparkSession.scala:745)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:402)
```

The Class X has `Set<>` and `ZonedDateTime` fields in it. Is it because of these objects I'm getting this issue?
I've another class which has only Double and String fields inside it. For the JavaRDD of that Object creation of DataFrame is not failing.

So for class X the above issue is coming:

```
@Builder
@Value
@Wither
The Class X {

   ZonedDateTime dateTime;
   Set<String> set;
   Double d;
   String str;
}
```

For Y it is not coming:

```
@Builder
@Value
Class Y {
    Double d;
    String str;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `createDataFrame` in your stacktrace. Could you add the beginning of the stacktrace (I assume the full stacktrace is too long, but instead of cutting of the beginning, it's better to cut out the recursive middle). Also please provide a [MCVE]. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the post with the stack trace with createDataFrame in it.

Comment: @AkshayM- Have you resolved this issue?